# Is there any general way to control the external display menu from unix?

Tags: display, input

A lot of modern LCD monitors offer a menu to select the input source, change brightness, etc. 
I would like to access the features of this menu from the terminal on my computer (either Linux or OSX). 
Is this possible, generally, with any monitor that has a menu?
Is it possible, specifically with my Dell P2312H monitor?

Motivation: I would like to easily select the input source on one of my monitors without having to touch the monitor buttons.

PS: I know there are some displays (e.g. LG 29EA93) that let you split the screen and use the two input sources at the same time. That would also be cool to 'hack' as a feature in any monitor, but I doubt it is possible.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, not on a unix like OS, not on Windows, I think monitors simply aren't designed to be manipulated by whichever device they are connected to. This is why for example KVM switches were made. But if there is a way, I'd love nothing more than to know how. Some specific monitors might support this.

Comment: It _may_ be possible via DDC, which already lets you control some monitor features even over a plain VGA cable.

Comment: What you're basically looking for is something talking DDC/CI I suspect.

Comment: @grawity and/or Journeyman Geek:  I found the utility ddccontrol thanks to your comments. Unfortunately, I have not got it to recognize the DCC/CI support which my Dell monitors are supposed to have. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

An option with HDMI, is if both a monitor and graphics card supported [HDMI-CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC). That said, I don't believe many, if any, graphics cards have this support.

I'm not sure why exactly, potentially due to licencing reasons and one more thing to support, but this technology gives the power to control various functions on a TV/Monitor:

> - **One Touch Play** allows devices to switch the TV to use it as the active source when playback starts
> - **System Standby** enables users to switch multiple devices to standby mode with the press of one button (except LG TV's)
> - **Preset Transfer** transfers the tuner channel setup to another TV set
> - **One Touch Record** allows users to record whatever is currently being shown on the HDTV screen on a selected recording device
> - **Timer Programming** allows users to use the electronic program guides (EPGs) that are built into many HDTVs and set-top-boxes to
>     program the timer in recording devices like PVRs and DVRs
> - **System Information** checks all components for bus addresses and configuration
> - **Deck Control** allows a component to interrogate and control the operation (play, pause, rewind etc.), of a playback component (Blu-ray
>     or HD DVD player or a Camcorder, etc.)
> - **Tuner Control** allows a component to control the tuner of another component
> - **OSD Display** uses the on-screen display (OSD) of the TV set to display text
> - **Device Menu Control** allows a component to control the menu system of another component by passing through the user interface (UI)
>     commands
> - **Routing Control** controls the switching of signal sources
> - **Remote Control Pass Through** allows remote control commands to be passed through to other devices within the system
> - **Device OSD Name Transfer** transfers the preferred device names to the TV set
> - **System Audio Control** allows the volume of an AV receiver, integrated amplifier or preamplifier to be controlled using any remote
>     control from a suitably equipped device(s) in the system

I have a suspicion you could get a USB device that could add this signal though, perhaps search `USB to HDMI CEC` if you wanted to investigate this option.

Comment: Only works with HDMI, no?

Comment: What about DVI?

Comment: @Cestarian I don't believe it's carried over DVI, only HDMI.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I guess I should have looked up his monitor first, didn't spot that, whoops..!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your specific monitor supports it, but many monitors do support `DDC/CI` (display data channel control interface) which allows to control several monitor parameters like brightness, input selection, etc. from the PC.

On Windows I used https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/control_my_monitor.html

It seems like https://github.com/ddccontrol/ddccontrol might allow to do the same on Linux, but I have not tested that.